# What's the easiest way, to post on my Facebook Wall through my Ruby on Rails App?

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

last week, I integrated successfully twitter with my "small" rails app. If I create a new record in my rails app it will be posted on twitter.

But how Do I do this with facebook? Twitter was really easy (thanks to the Twitter gem) 
Can you recommend a gem? A link to an example app would also be nice.

Thanks in advance 
cheers tabaluga

p.s. Oh, I forgot to mention, I do not have a personal facebook account. The Facebook Wall is a Company site.

Comment: have you did post on the company wall? is it a fanpage? i did just posted on my wall (user profile, not the company page) me = FbGraph::User.me(access_token).accounts this command is returning an Exception error. any advice? what version are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) and I really like it, very easy to use.
To post to a Wall you simply do:

```
 me = FbGraph::User.me(access_token)
 me.feed!(
    :message => '',
    :link => '',
    :name => '',
    :description => ''
  )
```

Comment: Great answer but how do I get the access token for me to post to my own pages?