# Easy way of posting on Facebook page (not a profile but a fanpage)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Which option is the best and easy way to post text or some other content on a Facebook page?

I'm looking for a direct way to put something there from my Rails application.

For instance, clicking on a button and automatically posting on my application and sending data to the facebook page?

I've built one for Twitter and the method I have looks like this:

```
def tweet(url)
  Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = APP_CONFIG['twitter_consumer_key']
    config.consumer_secret = APP_CONFIG['twitter_consumer_secret']
    config.oauth_token = APP_CONFIG['twitter_access_token']
    config.oauth_token_secret = APP_CONFIG['twitter_secret_token']
  end    
  shorted_url = shorten_url(url)
  Twitter.update("#{title} - #{shorted_url}")
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can follow this link
[What's the easiest way, to post on my Facebook Wall through my Ruby on Rails App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108932/whats-the-easiest-way-to-post-on-my-facebook-wall-through-my-ruby-on-rails-app/4890921#4890921)

this is how my method look like:

```
def facebook_it(url)
  pages = FbGraph::User.me(APP_CONFIG['facebook_access_token']).accounts.first
  shorten_url = shorten_url(url) # create a bit.ly link
  pages.feed!(
    :message => "#{title}",
    :link => shorten_url,
    :description => "#{content[0..280]}"
  )
end
```

also I've created another method:

```
def share(url)
  tweet(url)
  facebook_it(url)
end
```

so I call it this way from the controller:

```
def publish
  url = job_url(@job)
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  @job.publish
  @job.share(url)
  ..
end
```

I don't know if this is the better approach, but it's working nice for me.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

Since I had to mix up a few different articles to get it all set up I would add that for one developper being admin on a client's Facebook page you will have to :

1. Go to the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
2. Choose the app you created from the dropdown menu (if you didn't, create one)
3. Click "Get Access Token"
4. Click "Extended Permissions" tab
5. Choose both the manage_pages and the publish_stream permissions
6. Click "Get Access Token"
7. A window may open to ask you to confirm, say yes
8. Use the newly generated Access Token

Comment: Actually not really. I admit the general look of the procedure is the same because I based my answer on it (much thanks to its author). Though the content is not the same and I added extra details I had to discover on my own because the previous answer wasn't accurate enough. Hence my answer.