# Facebook posting help, adding to facebook whenever a user creates a post

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, facebook-graph-api

I think this question is a matter of writing nice ruby code, let me see what you guys think. I've already setup all the auth/access token stuff with omniauth and and fbgraph, what I can't seem to work out is how to integrate it when a user creates a post.

My app revolves around users making posts (made up of 'title' and 'content'), I'd like the post to be automatically shared on facebook or twitter or both, depending on the particular authentications the users has setup. And not share anywhere if the user has signed up conventionally without facebook/twitter.

How would I integrate a dynamic way to share the title and content of a user's post whenever they post automatically? I was thinking of some type of after_save to the post model but I can't get it working right. Thank you for any help is it very much appreciated.Also it would great if it was a method that allowed for furture expansion if I wanted to share links and pictures later on.

This is the only post while searching that sheds some light about sharing to both but I'm still confused :( 
[Easy way of posting on Facebook page (not a profile but a fanpage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883699/easy-way-of-posting-on-facebook-page-not-a-profile-but-a-fanpage/5480187#5480187)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Post` model have:

```
after_commit :share_content

def share_content
  user.share_content title, content
end
```

Then in `User` model have:

```
def share_content title, content
  # some conditionals with whatever stuff you have to determine whether
  # it's a twitter and/or facebook update...

  if go_for_twitter
    twitter.update title
  end

  if go_for_facebook
    facebook.feed! :message => title
    # ...etc.
  end
end
```